# Matlab: Create a matrix from a row vector according to specifications

Tags: matlab

I am working in **matlab**. I have a row vector `in` and a scalar number `fuzzy_no`. I want to create a matrix `output` of size `fuzzy_no x (numel(in)-fuzzy_no)`. such that the `ith` col of the matrix `output` has the elements from `i:i+fuzzy_no-1` of row vector `in`.

In other words I want to implement the following loop  without using loops

```
n = numel(in);
output = zeros(fuzzy_no,n-fuzzy_no);
for i = 1:size(output,2)
   output(:,i) = in(1,i:i+fuzzy_no-1);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in your example the last element from `in` is missing in the `output`. Assuming you want all the elements, you could use indexing like so:

```
[ii, jj] = meshgrid(1:fuzzy_no, 0:n-fuzzy_no);
output = in(ii+jj)
```

Or you could use the slightly more satisfying `hankel` built-in:

```
output = hankel(in(1:fuzzy_no), in(fuzzy_no:end))
```

Comment: I need the last element to be missing. So, using `end = numel(in)- 1 ` in `hankel` worked fine for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
n = numel(in);
lim1 = n-fuzzy_no

t1 = bsxfun(@times,in',ones(1,lim1)) %//'
uind = triu(ones(size(t1)),1)>0
lind = [zeros(fuzzy_no,lim1) ; tril(ones([size(t1,1)-fuzzy_no lim1]))]>0
t1(uind | lind)=[];
output = reshape(t1,fuzzy_no,n-fuzzy_no)
```